# Java heap space error. Android Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, ide

I keep getting the error "Java Heap Space" in my Eclipse IDE. After which Eclipse crashes and all unsaved data is lost.

[image: Error Screen]

It is happening on some particular layout XMLs only, right after I alter any property in it. Especially the ones with GridViews, listviews and tableviews. Also only in graphical layout mode not in XML mode.

This is one of the XML:

[image: XML]

I also checked the task manager during the time the change is made. And at that point my CPU usage increases from 32% to 74%. Sometimes even in the 90s.
My idle (when eclipse is not running) Memory usage is 2.01GB and during Eclipse operations it increases to 3.5GB.
[image]

The computer's configuration is:
[image]

From what I figured I believe the problem is that my RAM is inadequate. But I want to be sure before I upgrade the RAM. Am I right?

FYI: I have tried the solutions posted on other posts. For example, the "Run Configuration " ( I cannot seem to find what they are talking about" and the "Turning off Lint" ( This is not acceptable to me as I need the Lint ).

Answer (score 0):

In installation folder of eclipse, there would be a file eclipse.ini.

Increase the size of the following variable

-XX:MaxPermSize to some higher value than existing, for eg it its 512m , increase it upto 1024m and so on and check if you are getting the same error or not.

Comment: Changed the value from 256m to 1024 in Eclipse.ini. The same problem is  occuring!

Comment: -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m     
-Xms512m     
-Xmx1024m

These are the current values.

Comment: In that case, try changing the -Xmx to some higher value, in my case also I was getting the same error, only changing the MaxPermSize did the trick for me.